# Check 32-bit through code with different environment?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, 32bit-64bit

I know that `IntPtr.Size`  can check 64bit or 32 bit. (`8 || 4` bytes)

question :

is `IntPtr.Size` regarding to

- the operating system platform

or

- .net compiled version ( i can compile to 32 or to 64 )

*can you please check and correct this table ?*

```
compiled to | running OS | IntPtr.Size
______________________________________
      64             32       wont run
      64             64         8
      32             32         4
      32             64         4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is correct, as long as your "running on" column refers to the bitness of the OS, not the bitness of the CPU.

Keep in mind that there are actually three options: 32, 64 and AnyCPU:

```
    compiled to | running on      | IntPtr.Size
___________________________________________
      64        |    32           | won't run
      64        |    64           |  8
      32        |    32           |  4
      32        |    64           |  4
      AnyCPU    |    32           |  4
      AnyCPU    |    64           |  8
```

Comment: .Net 4.5 has a new option: [Any CPU 32-bit preferred](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11.aspx).

Comment: @Polynomial sorry for editing your answer. i thought it was my table... reverting...

Comment: question : im on 64 bit process. i also have a dll which was compiled to 32 bit. this dll has a Method which gets as parameter - int. since the dll was compiled to 32 bit - the size of the int is 4 byte. but if my 64 bit process  calls this function with its own int - it will send the method8 byte int...so what will happend ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd write the table like this:

```
     target  |     OS     | IntPtr.Size
______________________________________
      x64          32       wont run
      x64          64         8
   AnyCPU          32         4
   AnyCPU          64         8
      x86          32         4
      x86          64         4
```

With a strong hint that you always want to target AnyCPU and never x64.  Only target x86 if you know that you'll need to use unmanaged code (COM server typically) that is only available in 32-bit machine code.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are other use cases for explicitly setting x86, for example dealing with .NET libraries that have been compiled to x86 by external vendors. I've seen people develop on 32-bit machines, leave the target as AnyCPU, then have the code crash on 64-bit customer machines because the 32-bit library won't load.

Comment: Well, that's fixable, just run corflags.exe to the change it.

Comment: @HansPassant if `only the OS matters. ` so why the last 2 lines are the same ( with different OS) ?

Comment: Sure, but sometimes that causes problems in of itself. I once had the pleasure of dealing with a graphics library that interfaced with native code, but was never designed to work with 64-bit. The developer did everything on a 32-bit box and targeted 32-bit. When I manually changed it, the whole thing blew up because pointer sizes were different. In the end I just had to ship the whole thing as 32-bit only.

Comment: Because targeting x86 forces the bitness of the process to 32, even on a 64-bit OS.  Just as targeting x64 forces to 64.  AnyCPU sorts it out automatically.

Comment: AnyCPU currently means "use 64-bit if possible, otherwise drop back to 32-bit", hence the difference. In future, it'll have different connotations when ARM instruction sets are supported.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get this in the right order.
When you compile your code to IL, you can choose 32, 64 or Any CPU.
When the IL gets JIT compiled to native, it looks at that It's in the PE header). If you've forced bitness it will JIT (except if you forced 64 bit and you are on a 32 bit OS!) to the bitness of the OS.

So sizeof will tell you the bitness of the native code your IL has been compiled to.

You cannot rely on it to tell you the bitness of the processor (32 bit OS on a 64 bit chip)

and you cannot rely on it to tell you the bitness of the OS (32 bit process on 64 bit OS)

If it comes back as 8 you are on 64 bit OS and therefore must be on 64 bit chip, because there's no other way that can happen, until we get to 128 bit chip and OS anyway...

If it comes back 4 then you have to do different checks to discover the bitness of the OS or the chip.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Opertaing system platofrm, and *not* target compilation type.

Comment: Target compilation type does make a difference. If you compile to 32-bit, and run on a 64-bit OS, you won't get 64-bit code.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: it *seems* to me it says exactly the same.. So 32/64 bit is all about os and not processor..isn't it?

Comment: This answer is correct, but it's not very clear. If you compile to 32-bit, you'll get `IntPtr.Size == 4` on both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems. If you compile to 64-bit, you'll get `IntPtr.Size == 8` on 64-bit operating systems, but the code won't run on 32-bit operating systems. If you compile to AnyCPU, you'll get `IntPtr.Size == 4` on 32-bit operating systems, and `IntPtr.Size == 8` on 64-bit systems. See the table on my answer for a clearer summary.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: You have a wrong data, on 64 bit OS, if the software compiled for 32bit, IntPtr.Size will still be `4`.

Comment: @Tigran thats what ive written isnt it ? `32             64         4`

Comment: @Tigran still i have a problem with @hans answer `Yes, only the OS matters. ` but in the last 2 lines of his table there are same results with different OS ....so?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: you define a target of compilation, but the OS finally "decides" how it *can* run, that's why it's valuable to note, that even on differnt types of OS but with the *same* compilation target you get the same result. In this case 64bit OS decides to run you insied 32bit env.. That's why only OS matters at the end.